# MongoDB / Mongoose - Adding new database entry crashes page

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have problem with adding a `team` to my database, I have an index page at the moment which is just showing all of the teams in the database at the moment. When I go to this `localhost:3000/team` which is seen below for `team.jade`, I enter team name and press the submit button. When I then go to the index page, there it is, my new team is there.

But when I press the submit button, I actually get an error saying:

```
Express
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'teamName' of undefined
at module.exports (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/routes/index.js:126:24)
at callbacks (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:37)
at param (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:134:11)
at pass (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:141:5)
at Router._dispatch (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:169:5)
at Object.router (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:32:10)
at next (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.handle (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/app.js:34:5)
at next (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.static (/home/declan/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:55:61)
```

I'm not sure why I get this, line 126 of `index.js` is actually this line from below:

`var name = teamForm.teamName;`

This is one of the first lines creating the new database entry, so if it couldn't read that property, it isn't adding it to the database. That was my thinking, but when I reload the index page, there is my new database entry, so why do you think it isn't working?

index.js @ routes

```
/**
  * Add a new Team to database
  */
  app.post('/team', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url[GET] ' + req.route.path);
    var teamForm = req.body.teamForm;
    var name = teamForm.teamName;

    var newTeam = new Team();
    newTeam.name = name;

    newTeam.save(function(err, savedTeam){
      var message = '';
      var retStatus = '';
      if(!err){
        util.log('Successfully created team with Name : ' + name);
        message = 'Successfully created new team : ' + name;
        retStatus = 'success';
      } else {
        util.log('Error while creating team : ' + name + ' error : ' + util.inspect(err));
        if(err.code === 11000){
          message = 'Team already exists';
        }
        retStatus = 'failure';
      }
      res.json({
        'retStatus' : retStatus,
        'message' : message
      });
    });
  });
```

team.jade @ views (html template, you can see the needed id's etc)

```
extends index

block content
    div.row-fluid
        div.span9
            h2 New Team
            div.well.sidebar-nav
                div.teamList
                    form.form-horizontal(method="post", id="team-form")
                        div.control-group
                            label.control-label(for="teamName") Team Name :
                            div.controls
                                input.input-small(type="text", id="teamName")
                        div.control-group
                            div.controls
                                button#teamConfirm.btn.btn-primary.btn-mini(href='#') To DB
                br
                p This page is used to demonstrate how an 8 team single elimination tournament would be represented in the final design of my project. The pseudo code conjured up in my initial hand-in document was originally used here to produce the same result. The pseudo code helped create this set of seeded brackets, so that the matches correspond to the seeds of the tournament. For the 8 team bracket, I worked back through from the final, where seeds 1 and 2 should face each other, until I was left at round 1 of the brackets. This was used to give myself a 'new' set of seeds which were in the correct order to just be placed into these brackets.
        div.span3
            div.well.sidebar-nav
                h4 To-Do List:
                p - Enter list of teams manually from this page.
                p - Do a test to show a bracket with random seed.
                p - Show rankings after tournament
```

team.js @ js

```
var newTeam = function(){
    $('#teamConfirm').click(function(){
        newTeam.teamForm();
    });
};

newTeam.teamForm = function(){

    var teamForm = {
        teamName : $('#teamName').val()
    };
    // Basic validation
    $.post('/team', {'teamForm' : teamForm}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    });
};

newTeam();
```

index.js @ js

```
var Main = {};

Main.loadScript = function(url){
  var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;

  footer.appendChild(script);
}

$(document).ready(function(response){
  Main.loadScript('js/login.js');
  Main.loadScript('js/signup.js');
  Main.loadScript('js/team.js');
});
```

Comment: The reason for that error is because teamForm is undefined. Now why it is undefined is another issue...

Comment: Correct, it says its undefined which is why its causing the crash, but on that line, if it was undefined i wouldnt have thought it would have created the new database entry

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is because `req.body` is not being parsed to JavaScript object ( it remains as JSON string ). First check whether you are using

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

**before** any route. If it is not that, then try using `.ajax` instead of `.post` with `contentType` set:

```
$.ajax({
    // some other settings
    contentType : "application/json"
});
```

It might be that content types are messed up and Express is not parsing JSON string received from the client. The other thing you might try is simply doing ( on the server side ):

```
app.post('/team', function(req, res) {
    var body = JSON.parse( req.body );
    // other code
}
```

Perhaps wrapping the additional line with `try{}catch{}` block.

Comment: Yes, I have `app.use(express.bodyParser());` set in my `app.js` file. If I add the `JSON.parse` line of code to my `app.post` I get the following error: `Express
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
at Object.parse (native)` Any ideas?

Comment: I've not used these ajax calls before so I tried using your 2nd option instead as I wouldn't know how to code this with `$.ajax`

Comment: Also it doesn't add anything to the database if I use your `JSON.parse`

Comment: This is the order in which the errors occur: `23 Dec 15:10:18 - Serving request for url[GET] /team23 Dec 15:10:18 - Successfully created team with Name : Czech Republic`
`23 Dec 15:10:18 - Serving request for url[GET] /team`
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'teamName' of undefined`